# Mechanical Power and time to Mechanical energy

Tags: classical-mechanics

I have these two sets of data, the first being a time stamp (ms) and the other being mechanical power (W). For each of these I have to work out the mechanical energy in KWh.

```
0   0
362 3.76
402 3.76
442 7.12
482 10.68
522 12.46
562 16.02
602 17.80
```

From my working out I have created the formula:

```
ME = (T-O)/3600000)x(P/1000)
ME = Mech energy
T = Current Time
O = Previous time
P = Power
```

But I have no means of checking if it is actually right. Can someone please confirm?

Answer (score 1):

*Energy* is the integral of *Power* over time.
 Since your data for power vs. time are discrete, you shall first of all decide for a *reasonable* (or *acceptable*, or *hypothesized*) interpolation of a continuous $P(t)$ with respect to the available data.
If your interpolation is *stair-wise* and you assume that the recorded value of power extends to the precedent $\Delta t$ (e.g. in the first interval $0..362$ you assume $P=3.76$) then your formula is correct: $E_n=P_n \dot (t_n-t_{n-1}) \quad |\;1 \leqslant n$.
Probably, a better approximation is to take that the power varies linearly between the recorded values, so that:
$E_0=0, \quad E_1= 1/2(P_1-P_0)(t_1-t_0),\quad \cdots$ (which is a trapezoidal approx.).
But you could make a more sophisticated approximation by using a spline or polynomial interpolation and then take the integral.